# Unfortunately, app has stopped, unable to start activity?

Tags: android, xml

I'm very new to android and java and trying to make my first app. I tried to run the application on the emulator but it said "Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped". I'm using android studio.

```
06-17 18:41:24.788 2264-2264/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main process: skripsi.garden, PID: 2264 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{skripsi.garden/skripsi.garden.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at skripsi.garden.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at skripsi.garden.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at skripsi.garden.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I designed the layout by drag-and-drop from dragging stuff from the palette. But I couldn't drag anything to activity_user_main.xml. Since there's content_user_main and I can put stuff from the palette there, so I designed it there and somehow the activity_user_main turned out to look like the content_user_main automatically.

this is the content_user_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/foliagemain"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".UserMainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_main">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/selamatdatang"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBio"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonbiodata"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHelp" />"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonList"
        android:src="@drawable/buttondaftartaman"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonWeather" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonhelp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonWeather" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buttoncuaca" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the activity_user_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="skripsi.garden.UserMainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_user_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line 
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: convert your projects image from here http://compressjpeg.com/

Comment: The error is in the RelativeLayout in XML: likely, one of the xml properties has wrong value (for example, drawable is not exists). Check it more attentively.

Comment: have you attached appcompat-v7 lib into project?

Comment: @Robert where can I check it?

Comment: @KhizarHayat I did and it did nothing?

Comment: @omghelpz build.gradle - but just to be sure check two of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

> content_user_main.xml

has a problem. Second element in RelativeLayout is :

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBio"
    android:src="@drawable/buttonbiodata"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonHelp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHelp" />"/>
```

Delete `"/>` from the end, it is causing your problems.